# Should I use Options -Indexes with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, security

I noticed that if I go to mysite.com/wp-includes/ then it shows all the files in that folder and I would like to disable it (I think that it's a security vulnerability).

After searching online I found an easy solution (adding Options –Indexes in the .htaccess file) but I'm wondering if this may cause any problems with Wordpress or with Google indexing my website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use that [(along with plenty other htaccess security measures)](https://github.com/chrisblakley/Nebula/blob/master/Nebula-Child/examples/.htaccess-root) with all my WordPress sites:

I use:

```
Options All -Indexes
```

In my root .htaccess file and have never had issues with either WordPress or search crawlers.

I also have an [additional .htaccess file](https://github.com/chrisblakley/Nebula/blob/master/Nebula-Child/examples/.htaccess-uploads) in my /uploads directory for additional security precautions. Some of it may be overkill, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks GreatBlakes, you're great!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block from your Apache put this in your virtualhost:

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/public>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restart your apache and it is done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall) very popular security plugin blocks directory listing by adding to htaccess file:
    Options -Indexes

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39739848/12339395) answer, this is more secure than:
    Options All -Indexes