# What is the "All" in Options All -Indexes in .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What is the "All" in `Options All -Indexes` in .htaccess file?

Is it better than simple `Options -Indexes` line in .htaccess file of root folder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Options All`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/core.html#options) means all options except MultiViews. The options list is :

- ExecCGI
- FollowSymLinks
- Includes
- IncludesNOEXEC
- Indexes

`Options All -Indexes` means all options except MultiViews and Indexes for the folder.

It's better to specify only the options you want for this specific folder, ie with `All`, your server can execute CGI scripts on this directory (ExecCGI flag, is it what you really want?)

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you downvote, I could correct my answer?